# How to safely flush and stop a FileAppender in log4j2?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, junit, log4j2

I have a testing framework which uses a RoutingAppender to route each test's logs to its own file.

The configuration looks like this:

```
    Routing:
      - Name: TestCaseRouted
        Routes:
          Pattern: "${ctx:TestCaseId}"
          Route:
            - File:
                Name: TestCaseLogs
                FileName: "${ctx:TestCaseId}.log"
                Append: false
            - key: "${ctx:TestCaseId}"
```

At the end of each test, I use `FileUtils.readFileToByteArray` from commons IO to fetch the bytes and publish it to a reporter.

```
    // Junit5 extension
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext context) {
        deleteCurrentLogAppender();
        ThreadContext.clearMap();
        final File logFile = new File(getTestCaseId() + ".log");
        if (logFile.exists()) {
            byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(logFile)); 
            // Publish bytes to reporter
        }
    }

    private void deleteCurrentLogAppender() {
        final LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        RoutingAppender routingAppender = loggerContext.getConfiguration().getAppender("TestCaseRouted");
        routingAppender.deleteAppender(getTestCaseId());
    }
```

I am facing issues here since the FileAppender seems to truncate the file to keep writing unflushed logs during or after it has been deleted (which seems to call Appender.stop() internally) and the file is being read to the byte array.

In cases where the write happens midway, I get the below exception from `FileUtils.readFileToByteArray`:
`IOException: Unexpected read size, current: 4096, expected: 6084`

In other cases, I would have an incomplete log in the published report.

**How do I completely flush and stop the FileAppender from mutating the file before I can proceed from reading the log file?**

Comment: Do it from outside the application tested after it stopped?

Comment: I would, but there are other constraints that prevent me from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that log4j2 supports that scenario. One option is to [completely shutdown log4j2 in code](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.4/faq.html#shutdown):

```java
// import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
// import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
     
// get the current context
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext();
Configurator.shutdown(context);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still need the rest of the logging to continue as they are written to other test files after the current one finishes. I am not inclined to believe it is not possible, but rather that it's buried in the not-so-well-documented log4j classes. For instance `FileAppender` exposes a `stop(final long timeout, final TimeUnit timeUnit)` which is indicative of some sort of wait for a resource release.

Comment: It is not a common usage of log4j2 so it is probably not documented, if even possible.